# Flutter, how to reuse same stream connection

Tags: flutter, dart

Assume it already has a stream connection (firebase snapshots)

and in the other page, I want to reuse this stream connection inside the StreamBuilder()

However, since this connection is already in use by another streambuilder, only connection.waiting appears in the new screen.

I think this is a common issue how to solve this?

---

I think it`s called broadcast problem

`Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

I stored my stream connection in here

Comment: But you will miss all the previously emitted data as a stream only emits values to subscriber after the subscription.

Comment: @Rahul Yes I know so I stored previous data somewhere and showing up in new screen from that resource. anyway always showing up at first time (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) this got me headache

Comment: I checked out the docs for StreamBuilder. It looks like you will be getting ConnectionState.waiting as the stream has already emitted some values. It will be changed to ConnectionState.active or ConnectionState.done if new data arrives or connection is closed.

Comment: @Rahul You are correct so that is the now problem. It has to go to ConnectionState.active, but it is waiting until data is delivered, so you have to request new data for triggering inevitably. Do you know how to bypass ConnectionState.Waiting?

Comment: You can add initial data which you received from the other widget. Try doing that